# Link for destroy returns "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have the**Topics** controller and in the `view/topics/index.html.erb` the link for destroying item:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',topic, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

I tried also

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', topic_path(topic), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

but both returns

> undefined method topic_path for Class:0x00000105056a80>:
>   0x00000105047328>

in **routes.rb** is following:

```
  namespace :admin do
    ...
    resources :topics
  end
```

Where could be the problem and how to in the easily way to solve it? I was checking the other generated controllers/views by CRUD, and the setup is always the same and in all other controllers it's working well, just in this one I am getting over and over again this error.

Comment: Are you using instance variables (e.g. `@topic`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', admin_topic_path(topic), 
                                    confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

To make sure run command `rake routes`, in the result you should see your route.